# Any way to solve "Time Limit Exceeded"

Tags: python, binary, runtime

The code is to count the numbers in a range, converted to binary form, that doesn't have consecutive ones "11" in

```
class Solution(object):
    def findIntegers(self, n):
        if 1 <= n <= pow(10,9):
            count=0
            for item in range(n+1):
                num=str("{0:b}".format(item))
                if "11" not in num:
                    count+=1
        else:
            raise ValueError
        return count
```

I believe it returns the correct output, but it returns **"Time Limit Exceeded"** for my leet code problem for the input of "100000000"

Ran the code with this input, and Yeah it is very slow. I wanted to enhance the run time quality but couldn't think of a new way **other than using looping & .format()**

[Here is the line to the problem that I'm stuck on for those who might want more details.](https://leetcode.com/explore/challenge/card/july-leetcoding-challenge-2021/611/week-4-july-22nd-july-28th/3826/)

Comment: there is likely a pattern to it that you are missing (ie you shouldnt have to search the space to know the answer)

Comment: OMG. Look at him posting a LEETCODE question on SO. XD

Comment: The LeetCode [solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/non-negative-integers-without-consecutive-ones/solution/) is available for free and offers a better explanation than you'll likely get here.

Answer (score 2):

as mentioned in the comments, [the solution is available at leet code](https://leetcode.com/problems/non-negative-integers-without-consecutive-ones/solution/) and pretty well explained, however here is a python implementation that is commented

```
def recursive_find_nums(binaryLen, sumSoFar, targetNum, lastDigit):
    if sumSoFar > targetNum:
        # we have exceeded the limit, this number does not count
        return 0
    if (1 << binaryLen) > targetNum:
        # the next depth will exceed our limit
        # but this number counts
        return 1
    zeros = recursive_find_nums(binaryLen+1,sumSoFar,targetNum,0)
    if lastDigit == 1:
        # since lastDigit is 1 we can only add 0 to our binary string
        return zeros
    else:
        # since lastDigit == 0 we can add 1 or 0 to our string
        ones = recursive_find_nums(binaryLen+1,sumSoFar + (1 << binaryLen),targetNum,1)
        return zeros + ones
```

consider binary of `1010`(9 which does not have 2 consecutive 1's), since this ends in zero we can add either a 1 or a zero,yielding either `10101` or `10100`

now we look at those 2 that match (as long as they dont exceed our target value)
sine `10100` still ends with zero we follow the same logic above

however, since `10101` ends with a 1 we can only add a zero to the end, if we were to add a 1 we would violate our rule, so `101010` is the only matching value we can get by adding a 1  or zero to the end

since we start at nothing we can add a 1 or a zero

`1` or `0`

`1` follows the 1 rule above (we can only extend it by a '0'),ergo `1 =>` 10 `as the only path that follows our rule (`10` is 2 in decimal)

for `0` we follow same as above `0 -> either 1 or 0 (so 2 branches work with our rules)

as we recursively increase our binaryLength and sum, we cover all allowed branches (as opposed to every value, but we do explore some bad branches that are pruned)

by the way here is the speed difference between your method and this method
(on log scale)
[image]
and without log scale
[image]

## Dang ...

its still too slow ... lol oh well use the other bit method